# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dataset_dog_breeds/train/airedale/airedale-87.jpg

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have a folder named `labeled_data2`. This folder contains images of dog breeds.

Each image is prefixed with the dog's breed.

I am trying to move all the images from `labeled_data2`, sorted by breed, to `dataset_dog_breeds/train` and `dataset_dog_breeds/test`. Here is an example of how it would look like at the end:

```
          `dataset_dog_breeds/train/boxer/boxer.jpg`
```

Now, I do not know if solving the error(look at the title) I am getting will move all the images from `labeled_data2` to their respective paths. But it is a start.

Here is the code:

```
# organize dataset into a useful structure
from os import makedirs
from os import listdir
from shutil import copyfile
from random import seed
from random import random
# create directories
dataset_home = 'dataset_dog_breeds/'
subdirs = ['train/', 'test/']
for subdir in subdirs:
        # create label subdirectories
        labeldirs = ['affenpinscher/', 'afghan_hound/','african_hunting_dog/'
                     'airedale/', 'american_staffordshire_terrier/',
                     'appenzeller/', 'australian_terrier/', 'basenji/',
                     'basset/', 'beagle/', 'bedlington_terrier/', 'bernese_mountain_dog/',
                     'black-and-tan_coonhound/', 'blenheim_spaniel/', 'bloodhound/',
                     'bluetick/', 'border_collie/', 'border_terrier/', 'borzoi/',
                     'boston_bull/', 'bouvier_des_flandres/', 'boxer/', 'brabancon_griffon/',
                     'briard/', 'brittany_spaniel/', 'bull_mastiff/', 'cairn/', 'cardigan/',
                     'chesapeake_bay_retriever/', 'chihuahua/', 'chow/', 'clumber/',
                     'cocker_spaniel/', 'collie/', 'curly-coated_retriever/', 'dandie_dinmont/',
                     'dhole/', 'dingo/', 'doberman/', 'english_foxhound/', 'english_setter/',
                     'english_springer/', 'entlebucher/', 'eskimo_dog/']
        for labldir in labeldirs:
                newdir = dataset_home + subdir + labldir
                makedirs(newdir, exist_ok=True)
# seed random number generator
seed(1)
# define ratio of pictures to use for validation
val_ratio = 0.25
# copy training dataset images into subdirectories
src_directory = 'labeled_data2/'
for file in listdir(src_directory):
        src = src_directory + '/' + file
        dst_dir = 'train/'
        if random() < val_ratio:
                dst_dir = 'test/'
        if file.startswith('affenpinscher'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'affenpinscher/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('afghan_hound'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'afghan_hound/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('african_hunting_dog'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'african_hunting_dog/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('airedale'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'airedale/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('american_staffordshire_terrier'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'american_staffordshire_terrier/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('appenzeller'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'appenzeller/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('australian_terrier'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'australian_terrier/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('basenji'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'basenji/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('basset'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'basset/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('beagle'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'beagle/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('bedlington_terrier'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'bedlington_terrier/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('bernese_mountain_dog'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'bernese_mountain_dog/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('black-and-tan_coonhound'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'black-and-tan_coonhound/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('blenheim_spaniel'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'blenheim_spaniel/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('bloodhound'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'bloodhound/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('bluetick'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'bluetick/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('border_collie'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'border_collie/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('afghan_hound'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'afghan_hound/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('afghan_hound'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'afghan_hound/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('bedlington_terrier'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'bedlington_terrier/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('bernese_mountain_dog'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'bernese_mountain_dog/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('black-and-tan_coonhound'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'black-and-tan_coonhound/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('blenheim_spaniel'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'blenheim_spaniel/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('bloodhound'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'bloodhound/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('bluetick'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'bluetick/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('border_collie'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'border_collie/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('border_terrier'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'border_terrier/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('borzoi'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'borzoi/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('bouvier_des_flandres'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'bouvier_des_flandres/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('boxer'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'boxer/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('brabancon_griffon'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'brabancon_griffon/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('briard'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'briard/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('brittany_spaniel'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'brittany_spaniel/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('bull_mastiff'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'bull_mastiff/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('cairn'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'cairn/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('cardigan'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'cardigan/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('chesapeake_bay_retriever'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'chesapeake_bay_retriever/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('chihuahua'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'chihuahua/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('chow'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'chow/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('clumber'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'clumber/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('cocker_spaniel'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'cocker_spaniel/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('collie'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'collie/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('curly-coated_retriever'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'curly-coated_retriever/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('dandie_dinmont'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'dandie_dinmont/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('dhole'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'dhole/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('dingo'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'dingo/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('doberman'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'doberman/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('english_foxhound'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'english_foxhound/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('english_setter'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'english_setter/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('english_springer'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'english_springer/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        if file.startswith('entlebucher'):
                dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'entlebucher/'  + file
                copyfile(src, dst)
        elif file.startswith('eskimo_dog'):
            dst = dataset_home + dst_dir + 'eskimo_dog/'  + file
            copyfile(src, dst)
```

Comment: may seem trivial, but is the filename incorrect? - By that I mean is the filename / folder for it spelled correctly - usually simple little things cause the most irritating errors

Comment: @JackWright I think so. I will double check.

Comment: Does this expect to create the directory or have you made them yourself?

Comment: @JackWright The program is suppose to make the directories and subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why I was getting the error was due to a trivial mistake. In the `labeldirs` list I forgot to put a comma after `'african_hunting_dog/'`.

Comment: Ah the comma second place hide and seek champion after the semi colon!

Comment: Then I suggest you would consider deleting the question